# Magento 2: Mailchimp subscribe on checkout checkbox

Tags: magento2, mailchimp

I setup Magemonkey/mailchimp on Magento 2 application. In my checkout page, I do not see checkbox to subscribe to mailchimp mailing list. I tried to configure it in Admin page, but I don't see the "Subscribe on checkout" option in the mailchimp general configuration in admin page. Why is it missing? What needs to be done to show this option?

Comment: Have you integrate checkbox of subscription to mailchimp mailing list?